# Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,0)

Tags: linux, filesystems, qemu, arm, emulation

I'm trying to run orange-pi emulation with [self-build linux kernel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EGFcyTnSAsu7PwjxApYYKa6qyv6XqjaE/view?usp=sharing) by this commands:

```
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make mrproper
ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make sunxi_defconfig

ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- make
```

and system generated with buildroot using default `orangepi_zero_defconfig`.
Trying to run emulation by this command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M orangepi-pc -nic user -nographic \
-kernel linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
-append 'root=/dev/mmcblk0 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw' \
-dtb linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3-orangepi-pc.dtb \
-drive file=sdcard.img,format=raw,if=sd \
-no-reboot
```

In boot logs i see this:

```
[    5.337453] List of all partitions: 
[    5.338217] b300         2097152 mmcblk0  
[    5.347713]  driver: mmcblk 
[    5.347884]   b301           61440 mmcblk0p1 4d1f495b-d662-4b1d-818a-591ebed99bac 
[    5.348161]  
[    5.348330] No filesystem could mount root, tried:  
[    5.349117]  ext4 
[    5.349219]   
[    5.349738] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,0)
```

Full log on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I6qXxFRvdjnH7QNkeu0IUsNmRU72pgbk/view?usp=sharing).

[zImage](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17wBszARTfebH5mGEo0jNPK7cBwEC8FT9/view?usp=sharing)

[dtb file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12ZDzK49mVlsvJXcudj0xVE1Wr0VLLHUd/view?usp=sharing)

Emulation stops with reboot message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## I've fixed this problem.

- Fix the system image 
  `fdisk sdcard.img`
  `>w`
- Fix kernel arguments in qemu command:

```
qemu-system-arm -M orangepi-pc -nic user -nographic \
-kernel linux/arch/arm/boot/zImage \
-append 'bootargs=console=ttyO0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p1 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait' \
-dtb linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun8i-h3-orangepi-pc.dtb \
-drive file=sdcard.img,format=raw,if=sd \
-no-reboot
```

Comment: Just so you know - it's perfectly allowable to accept your own answer by clicking on the check underneath the up-and-down voting arrows. Doing so gains you 15 reputation points. And it's a good answer, so I recommend that you accept it. :-)